# Where can I view a Bill Payment that only used Credits?

Tags: quickbooks

QuickBooks Premier Retail Edition 2012

1. I wrote a check to a vendor for a pre-payment deposit using Banking->Write Checks.
2. I enter a Bill Payment using Vendors->Pay Bills, selected a bill and used Set Credits to apply the deposit check from step #1
3. Now I cannot find the Bill Payment transaction anywhere and I'm about to go nuts!

I can see the Check transaction but there is NO Bill Payment record in the transaction list for the Vendor. If you pay a bill using only credits does QuickBooks not create a Bill Payment transaction?

I just did a test by paying another bill with a credit and can find no record of the transaction in the AP or check register. If I view the Bill that was paid I DO see the Check in the Related Transactions side panel but that's it - Now I can't even figure out how to delete what I've done!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try these things...when I am stuck, I just start browsing around.  Or Google.

1. Try drilling down from a report, like a paid parables
   report.
2. Thoroughly check the vendor center 10x.
3. If you have an audit log function in you QB version, it would give
   you the account.
4. Try browsing in the Chart of Accounts.  There may
   be a different account for all credit payments - like undeposited
   funds for transactions in but not in in.  ;)